# Python list object is not callable for a list of integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I always get the Error: 'List' object not callable... I looked around in Google and tried every given solution, but it's still the same.
I cannot get my code to work. I have a list of integers, and I need to give every element to different variables.

```
dmy = input('What is your date? Please put in like this: 2.11.2016')
dmy.strip(".")
dmy = [int(x) for x in dmy.split('.')]
list(dmy)
print(dmy)

dd = dmy(0)
mm = dmy(1)
yy = dmy(2)
```

The first part of the code is working. I get the error while trying to give the list element to another variable so this dmy(0) does not work. But it is in all the books I have this way?

I use python 3.5.2

Comment: Are you aware of difference between `something(1)` and `something[1]`?

Comment: a) Your `list(dmy)` is not doing anything because it always creates a new object, and you haven't assigned that new object anywhere - so Python will always discard it. And b) you want to do `dmy[0], dmy[1],...`, not `dmy(0), dmy(1)...`. The first is a function call, the latter is how you actually do list lookup. `dmy` is not a function so you should never have expected `dmy(0)` to work. Please find a Python tutorial.

Comment: Have you considered getting acquainted with the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/) or a [Python tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_quick_guide.htm)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you are trying to do. An element in the list is obtained by `list[index]` format. While you are trying to call as `list(index)` which python is interpreting as function call and hence throwing you error:

> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Corrected code:

```
dmy = input('What is your date? Please put in like this: 2.11.2016')
dmy.strip(".")
dmy = [int(x) for x in dmy.split('.')]
list(dmy)
print(dmy)

dd = dmy[0]
mm = dmy[1]
yy = dmy[2]
```

Comment: Oh damn... That an simple mistake....

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> dd = dmy[0]
>>> mm = dmy[1]
>>> yy = dmy[2]
>>> dd
2
>>> mm
11
>>> yy
2016
>>>
```